# How to use snap SVG in react with next and TS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js, snap.svg

## Issue

I am trying to use SnapSVG in my react project, but I cannot get it to run in the first place. Could someone help me with the proper settings? I am not very familiar with webpack so detailed instructions would be very much appreciated.

**error**

```
index.js?46cb:602 Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (FILEPATH/node_modules/snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js:485:3)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object.snapsvg (FILEPATH/.next/server/pages/index.js:1291:18)
at

**webpack_require**

(FILEPATH/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/components/domain/top-first-view/index.tsx:9:65)
```

**import in React components**

```
import * as Snap from 'snapsvg';
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "next": "^13.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sanitize.css": "^13.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.1"
 },
"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "imports-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "snapsvg": "^0.5.1",
    "@types/snapsvg": "^0.5.2",
    "cjs-loader": "^0.1.0",
    ...
},
  "volta": {
    "node": "18.6.0",
    "yarn": "1.22.19"
  }
```

## what I've tried so far

I have tried using `imports-loader` as is discussed in [this Github thread](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/341), but this resulted in a new error.

**new error after webpack settings**

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'FILEPATH/.next/server/pages/index.js'
at Object.openSync (node:fs:594:3)
at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:462:35)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:18)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object.requirePage (FILEPATH/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js:88:12)
at <unknown> (FILEPATH/Documents/GitHub/toda-web-art/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:37:73)
at async Object.loadComponents (FILEPATH/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:37:26)
```

**webpack config in next.config.js**

```
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: require.resolve('snapsvg'),
        use: 'imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0',
      },
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using the following `next.config.js` and `package.json`

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^13.4.9",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "snapsvg": "^0.5.1",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/snapsvg": "^0.5.3",
    "imports-loader": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules = [
      ...config.module.rules,
      {
        test: require.resolve("snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js"),
        use: "imports-loader?wrapper=windowadditionalCode=module.exports=0;",
      },
    ];
    config.resolve.alias.snapsvg = "snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js";
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Credit to [this Github issue](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/639) for providing the new config for Webpack Import Loader 4.x

Comment: What does this script do? Do you suggest editing the `package.json` file directly? Why not use `npm`? Add an explanation, please.